# Получение ответа используя WebRequest

Tags: c#

Провел много времени в поисковиках но ответа так и не нашел.

Я использую WebRequest для отправки запроса к API сайта. При отправке одновременно более 3х запросов, из одного приложения, время ответа начинает значительно увеличиваться, что мне крайне не подходит. Я написал вин форм приложение которое открывает консольные приложения которые отправляют эти же запросы и время ответа всегда одинаковое. То-есть, я запускаю одновременно 50 консольных и среднее время ответа остается в пределах нормы.

Собственно вопрос, что я делаю не так, что запустив 50 потоков в одном приложении сервис начинает отвечать по 10 секунд при том что 50 разных приложений делающих тоже самое получают результаты за 0.3 секунды.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне добиться такого же результата в одном приложении?

Ниже код запроса, но наврятли это важно, все стандартно.

```
            var request = WebRequest.Create(requestString);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: `Сlose` - точно делаете?

Comment: вполне возможно, что проблема в том как вы создаёте эти потоки :D (Больше кода. больше подробностей) Ну и как дополнение: сейчас не рекомендуется использовать WebRequest. Используйте лучше HttpClient c:

Comment: В блоке finaly делаю dataStream?.Dispose;

Comment: Потоки создаю new Thread(() => GetData(id)).Start();

Comment: Один поток что я создавал, делал последовательно по несколько сотен запросов без каких либо задержек, наврятли проблема в неправильном закрытии. И пока таких потока до 3-4х все нормально. Как только становится больше, то результаты запросов в каждом из потоков возвращаются дольше. Можно подумать не справляется процессор или канал интернет, но нет, при запуске того же самого в отдельных приложениях - все стабильно быстро. Я не знаю в какую сторону копать... HttpClient пробовал, результат тот же, но да, я заменю на него, спасибо. В чем может быть проблема с созданием потоков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю подойдет ли в качестве ответа. Во первых я перешел на HttpClient с WebRequest по рекомендации Kamushek, но это проблему не решило. После проведенных поисков и тестов оказалось что существует лимит на количество одновременных подключений к серверу. Задать лимит подключений можно вот этой строкой, это решило мою проблему.

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;
```

Помогла разобраться вот эта статья https://habr.com/ru/post/424873/